# How can I pass Javascript variable data to Template Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, template-toolkit

I am writing a form that takes zip code input. Javascript code determines city & state based on zip code. I would like the city and state to appear on a 'results' page that is displayed when the user completes the form. I can only get Template Toolkit to display the form input params on the result page. Is there a way to get the city and state to appear?

Comment: You'll need to pass the data via a URL string, local storage, or some other server-side mechanism. Without knowing anything about your site, there's not much more to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @isherwood notes, without more detail it's hard to say.

But I would suspect you might want to have whatever does your Javascript city/state decoding push their results into some hidden or uneditable form fields, so they make the round-trip to your server and are available for the next round of TT rendering.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wound up doing. I used type='hidden', changed all of the .innerHTML to .value, and passed the info to TT2. It works great.